# What is an antonym of 'cynical'?

Tags: word-choice, antonyms

Choose the correct antonym for 'cynical'.

(a) Gullible

(b) Equivocal

(c) Pessimistic

(d) Liberal

I chose 'gullible' as the answer, but I was wrong according to the answer sheet. I don't think 'Liberal' is the answer. Am I right?

Comment: I don't think that _any_ of the suggested antonyms are particularly 'correct'. If I wish to say that someone is 'not cynical', I'll probably say or write exactly that, or possibly use [uncynical](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/uncynical) or possibly [uncritical](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/uncritical)

Comment: I don't think so either. _Gullible_ seems to me the nearest to an antonym.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the options provided are right. The closest to being correct is probably "gullible". Appropriate antonyms of "cynical":

> optimistic, credulous, hopeful, uncynical

Answer (score -1):

I think antonyms are amiable, responsive,softhearted etc

Comment: The system has flagged this as low quality because of its length. Can you edit it to expand on why you have put these forward? None of them seems right to me.